# TYPO3 Plugin - One action public access and one private

Tags: authentication, controller, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I'm developing an extension that have both, a list of records (action `show`) and a form to send a new record (action `new`).

The list must be for public access, but the form must require a login form (I'm using the login form content type that comes with TYPO3).

I have tried using the Access Tab for the plugin selecting **Show at any Login** but it applies to the entire plugin not for each action.

Currently, this is how the page looks like:

[image]

How could I get to display the login form only when someone tries to create a new record?

Note: The extension is based on Extbase and Fluid. The target version is TYPO3 6.2.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to split the actions in different "views" with `switchableControllerActions` in your flexform. Then you would need to place separate plugins on two different pages, that way you can have different access configuration for the plugins. If you don't know how to adjust the flexform, you can post the content of it here.

The other way would be to make a check inside the controller, but i would only use it if you have a lot of different roles you need to check.

```
    if ($this->loginUser === null && $GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser && !empty($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid'])) {
        // the user is logged in
    } else {
        // return '' as action content
        return '';
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if the `new` action is inaccessible in the publicly accessible plugin if doing it this way - you'd probably just need to manipuate the URL of the public page and add the parameter `tx_<extname>_<pluginname>[action]=new` to it.

Comment: the point in configuring the `switchableControllerActions` is that only the configured actions can be called, all the other actions are nonexistent to the plugin. You can then choose the desired "view" in the plugin configuration

Comment: Seems you are right, to me that looked like it was only a display thing, and only the configuration from `configurePlugin` was taken into account. I stand corrected.